# Discord.js Is running both the "if" statement and the "else statement"

Tags: discord.js

So I'm coding  discord bot, and I have a statement that is supposed to only send a certain message if the second (Argument 1) argument is "version"
here's the code:

```
    case 'help':
                if(args[1] === 'version'){
                    message.channel.send(VERSIONDETAILS)
                }
                else
                message.channel.send('Command list for version ' + VERSION)
                message.channel.send('Prefix: ' + PREFIX)
                message.channel.send(`botdetails: Sends information on the bot \ninvite: Sends a permanent invite link \ninfo: Sends info on Brothaus \nversioninfo: Sends the version number, and latest version details` )
                break;
```

But when I run the b!help version command, it sends both the VERSIONDETAILS and the else statement messages. How do I solve this?

Edit: Gosh this was beyond a nimwit post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should look like this, you've forgotten {}

```js
case 'help':
    if (args[1] === 'version') {
        message.channel.send(VERSIONDETAILS)
    } else {
        message.channel.send('Command list for version ' + VERSION)
        message.channel.send('Prefix: ' + PREFIX)
        message.channel.send(`botdetails: Sends information on the bot \ninvite: Sends a permanent invite link \ninfo: Sends info on Brothaus \nversioninfo: Sends the version number, and latest version details`)
    }
    break;
```